# Rectangle around data points in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

If I have some data points in a pgfplot, how can I draw a rectangle around them, with the rectangle using the same coordinate system as the points?

I've included an example which does not work below.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\begin{axis}[xlabel=x, ylabel=y]
\addplot[smooth,mark=*,blue] plot coordinates {
    (0,2)
    (2,3)
    (3,1)
};
\addplot[red, thick,rounded corners] (0,-1) rectangle (0,0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

(Why is there a cross not a rectangle?)

From the manual I would expect that using:

```
\addplot[red, thick,rounded corners] (axis cs: 0,-1) rectangle (axis cs: 0,0);
```

might force the rectangle to use the same coordinate system as the points, but it does not, the code no longer compiles.

Answer (score 15):

If you want to add elements like that to an axis, don't use `\addplot` (you're not adding a plot, after all), but `\draw`, `\fill` or `\node`:

[image]

```
 \documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} % Makes the axis label placement prettier

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel=x, ylabel=y, ymin=0]
\addplot[smooth,mark=*,blue] plot coordinates {
    (0,2)
    (2,3)
    (3,1)
};
\draw [red, thick,rounded corners] (axis cs:-0.2,1.8) rectangle (axis cs:2.2,3.2);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```